# pyinstaller multiple files. Import .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I Have a problem.

I want to create a `.exe` file that will read my project. My project contains the following files: `Main.py`, `Data.py`, two images, and two folders.

`Main.py` imports `Data.py`, reads the images and saves the results in one of the folders. `Data.py` contains a class and stores data inside the class read from text files that are in the other folder.

How can I make a `.exe` file that will have all of those files and folders?

I can build a `.exe` file out of `Main.py` and paste all the files in the Main folder of the dist folder, but the `.exe` won't read `data.py`.

Thank you